# Why I get Client Connection Idle on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have an app deployed on Heroku and I'm trying to access that app from 2 different computers.
On the first computer, It loads everything and goes through and on the second computer I get

```
2023-05-20T23:23:50.261576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=warning code=H28 desc="Client Connection Idle" method=GET path="/users/getdata" host=host request_id=494accd1-7428-40b4-b92c-898934c20ed1 fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48857ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
```

both of them are connected to different internet connections.
Can someone explain how to fix this? Or why it is happening? On 1 computer is working and on the other is not...